# How to make float:left work in google chrome on linux

Tags: html, css

It's just on linux that this page renders incorrectly:

[image]

The circled content should be to the right like this

[image]

If I make a fiddle then it will look like it's working the rendering problem does not appear until I run it outside the fiddle and on linux. Do you have an idea what should be done? The HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html dir="ltr" lang="en-IN" class="js"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <meta name="keywords" content="Houses Apartments, Vacation homes, Offices, Land, Flatmates,Paying Guest, Other real estate, Cars, Motorcycles, Accessories  parts, Trucks, Other vehicles, Home  Garden, Clothing, For Kids (Toys  Clothes), Jewelry  Watches, Hobbies, Sports  Bicycles, Movies, Books  Magazines, Pets, Tickets, Art  Collectibles, Music  Instruments, Computers  Accessories, TV, Audio, Video, Cameras, Cellphones  gadgets, Video games  consoles, Job offers, Resumes, Services, Classes, Professional,Office equipment, Other,  ">
    <meta name="description" content="Find jobs, cars, houses, mobile phones and properties for sale in your region conveniently. Find the best deal among {{count}} free ads online!"> 


    <title>Free classifieds in India - KoolBusiness.com</title>
<style type="text/css">

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; }article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }body { line-height: 1; }ol, ul { list-style: none; }blockquote::before, blockquote::after, q::before, q::after { content: none; }.sprite_index_in_in_map { width: 450px; height: 499px; background-image: url(http://www.koolbusiness.com/img/index_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26); background-position: -2px -2px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; }.sprite_index_in_in_en_logo { width: 362px; height: 62px; background-image: url(http://www.koolbusiness.com/img/index_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26); background-position: -885px -2px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; }a:hover .sprite_common_pagi_left_right, a:hover.sprite_common_pagi_left_right { width: 9px; height: 26px; background-image: url(http://www.koolbusiness.com/img/common_in.png?7a24926f0c6af56cb192ff085c6b78aa95b80b16); background-position: -379px -30px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; }a:hover .sprite_common_pagi_right_left, a:hover.sprite_common_pagi_right_left { width: 9px; height: 26px; background-image: url(http://www.koolbusiness.com/img/common_in.png?7a24926f0c6af56cb192ff085c6b78aa95b80b16); background-position: -405px -2px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; }a:hover .sprite_common_pagi_left_left, a:hover.sprite_common_pagi_left_left { width: 9px; height: 26px; background-image: url(http://www.koolbusiness.com/img/common_in.png?7a24926f0c6af56cb192ff085c6b78aa95b80b16); background-position: -418px -2px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; }a:hover .sprite_common_pagi_right_right, a:hover.sprite_common_pagi_right_right { width: 9px; height: 26px; background-image: url(http://www.koolbusiness.com/img/common_in.png?7a24926f0c6af56cb192ff085c6b78aa95b80b16); background-position: -418px -30px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; }a:hover .sprite_common_topbar_settings, a:hover.sprite_common_topbar_settings { width: 35px; height: 24px; background-image: url(http://www.koolbusiness.com/img/common_in.png?7a24926f0c6af56cb192ff085c6b78aa95b80b16); background-position: -474px -2px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; }.sprite_common_facebook { width: 17px; height: 17px; background-image: url(http://www.koolbusiness.com/img/common_in.png?7a24926f0c6af56cb192ff085c6b78aa95b80b16); background-position: -614px -2px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; }.sprite_common_customer_service { width: 17px; height: 17px; background-image: url(http://www.koolbusiness.com/img/common_in.png?7a24926f0c6af56cb192ff085c6b78aa95b80b16); background-position: -614px -21px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; }#wrapper { position: relative; display: block; width: 948px; margin: 16px auto; text-align: left; }header { display: block; height: 64px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 16px; margin-bottom: 16px; }header h1 { margin: 0px; }footer.columns { padding-top: 16px; margin: 16px 0px 32px; font-size: 83.3%; line-height: 116.7%; clear: both; }footer.columns .widecolumn { padding-right: 8px; margin-bottom: 16px; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: rgb(170, 170, 170); }footer.columns .widecolumn .last { margin-bottom: 0px; }footer.columns aside { display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 201px; float: left; padding-left: 8px; margin: 0px 0px 16px -1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: rgb(170, 170, 170); }footer.columns aside a { display: block; clear: both; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 2px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: normal; }footer.columns aside i { width: 17px; float: left; text-align: center; }footer.columns aside span { padding-left: 8px; float: left; width: 176px; }#world_sites { display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(170, 170, 170); padding-top: 16px; }#world_sites a { font-weight: normal; }#world_sites p { margin: 0px; }.google_plus { height: 20px; }.alert-outer .alert-closer, .alert-outer .alert-closer:visited { float: right; display: block; opacity: 0.4; line-height: 30px; padding: 0px 10px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important; }.alert-outer .alert-closer:hover { text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.6; }.topbar a:link, .topbar a, .topbar a:visited { color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }.topbar-inner a:hover, .topbar-inner span:hover { text-decoration: underline; }.ie6 .topbar-inner a, .ie6 .topbar-inner a:visited { color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }.js .topbar-dropdown a:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); }.js .topbar-dropdown a, .js .topbar-dropdown a:visited, .js .topbar-dropdown a:hover { color: rgb(51, 51, 51); }html { height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; }body { background-color: rgb(255, 255, 235); font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); height: 100%; text-align: center; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; }a { cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }a:hover, a span:hover { text-decoration: underline; }a:link { color: rgb(51, 102, 153); }a:visited { color: rgb(153, 51, 102); }strong { font-weight: bold; }p { margin: 12px 0px; }p.first { margin-top: 0px; }p.last { margin-bottom: 0px; }ul, ol { margin: 12px 0px; padding-left: 32px; }ul { list-style-type: disc; }li { margin-bottom: 8px; }h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-weight: bold; margin: 4px 0px; }h1 { font-size: 183.3%; line-height: 30px; }h2 { font-size: 150%; line-height: 22px; }i { display: block; float: left; overflow: hidden; font-style: normal; }input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { -webkit-appearance: none; margin: 0px; }.button:hover { background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(229, 229, 229), rgb(244, 244, 244)); text-decoration: none; background-repeat: repeat no-repeat; }.button:active { background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; }input[type="button"].preset:hover, input[type="submit"].preset:hover, button.preset:hover { background-color: rgb(255, 200, 0); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(255, 177, 26), rgb(255, 200, 0)); text-shadow: rgb(255, 209, 117) -1px -1px 0px; background-repeat: repeat no-repeat; }input[type="button"]:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover, button:hover { background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(229, 229, 229), rgb(244, 244, 244)); text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) -1px -1px 0px; text-decoration: none; background-repeat: repeat no-repeat; }input[type="button"]:active, input[type="submit"]:active, button:active { background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; }.columns { overflow: hidden; display: block; height: 1%; }.columns .widecolumn { width: 730px; float: left; }.columns aside { width: 202px; float: left; margin-left: 16px; }.spritetext { display: block; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -99999px; }.nohistory a, a.nohistory, a .nohistory { color: rgb(51, 102, 153); }ul.bullets li::before { position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 0px; display: inline-block; width: 6px; height: 6px; margin: 0px 0px 0px -16px; background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0); content: ''; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; }header { border-bottom-width: 3px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(242, 102, 59); }#post { display: block; position: absolute; top: 16px; right: 0px; height: 46px; line-height: 46px; }#post a { color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-shadow: rgb(255, 244, 210) 1px 1px 2px; font-size: 20px; }#post a:hover, #post a span:hover { text-decoration: none; }footer { border-top-width: 3px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(242, 102, 59); }.main { overflow: hidden; display: block; }#mapcontainer, .column_left { float: left; display: block; overflow: hidden; }#mapcontainer { margin: 16px 0px 0px 32px; }.box { display: block; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid rgb(208, 208, 191); box-shadow: rgb(119, 119, 119) 0px 0px 1px; -webkit-box-shadow: rgb(119, 119, 119) 0px 0px 1px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 320px; padding: 16px; margin: 2px 2px 8px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; }.box h2 { font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-top: 0px; }.box ul { padding-left: 16px; margin: 0px; }.box li { margin-bottom: 4px; }#regions { float: left; display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 400px; margin-left: 4px; }#regions .regions_one, #regions .regions_two { float: left; width: 200px; }#regions h2 { display: block; clear: both; padding: 12px 0px 4px; margin: 0px; font-size: 14px; }#regions ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }#regions ul li { display: block; clear: both; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 0px; }#regions a { line-height: 20px; font-size: 13px; display: block; float: left; }#mapcontainer { position: relative; }#area_map { width: 450px; height: 499px; }#map_map { clear: both; position: static; }#map_map img { position: absolute; }.google_plus { position: absolute; right: 160px; top: 595px; }#ad { display: inline-block; border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 290px; height: 45px; font-size: 150%; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: bold; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(109, 179, 242) 0%, rgb(84, 163, 238) 50%, rgb(54, 144, 240) 51%, rgb(30, 105, 222) 100%); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; }


#likebtn{position:absolute;right:0px;top:595px;}
.google_plus{position:absolute;right:160px;top:595px;}

  #ad {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 290px;
    height: 45px;
font-size: 150%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: white; font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #6db3f2; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 50%, #3690f0 51%, #1e69de 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6db3f2), color-stop(50%,#54a3ee), color-stop(51%,#3690f0), color-stop(100%,#1e69de)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 50%,#3690f0 51%,#1e69de 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 50%,#3690f0 51%,#1e69de 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 50%,#3690f0 51%,#1e69de 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 50%,#3690f0 51%,#1e69de 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6db3f2', endColorstr='#1e69de',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

</style>
<!-- JAVASCRIPTS: -->
                 </script><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/1_files/jquery-1.js"></script>          

</head>
<body >
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="topbar-inner nohistory">
            <div class="topbar-left">
            <a class="topbar-new" href="https://www.koolbusiness.com/account/create"><strong>New!</strong> All your ads and saved searches in one place, create an account today!</a>

            </div>
            <div class="topbar-right">
                <a class="topbar-login last" href="/login" title="Login to your account" rel="nofollow">
                        <i class="sprite_common_topbar_log-in topbar-float_left"></i>
                        Log in  
                    </a>
                    <a class="topbar-create first" href="/create/" title="Create your account" rel="nofollow">  
                        <i class="sprite_common_topbar_logged-in topbar-float_left"></i>
                        Create account      
                    </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="wrapper">


    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <div class="alert-outer alert-error">
    <a href="#" class="alert-closer" title="close this alert" onclick="removeIeNotification(this); return false;">×</a>
    <div class="alert-inner">
        <span><strong>You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer.</strong> For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade today!</span>

    </div>
</div>

    <![endif]-->
<header>
<h1 id="logo" class="sprite_index_in_in_en_logo spritetext">koolbusiness.com - The right choice for buying &amp; selling in india</h1>











    <div id="post">
 <a href="/ai" id="ad">Post your ad for free</a>

</div>




    </header>

<div class="main">
    <div class="column_left">
        <div class="box">
            <h2>High quality classifieds</h2>
<ul><li>KoolBusiness  is easy, free, and kool.</li>
<li>Buy and sell <a href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/india/cars-for_sale">cars</a>, check our <a href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/india/real_estate">real estate</a> section, find <a href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/india/jobs">jobs</a>, and much more.</li>
<li>Check our <strong><a href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/india">3773 ads online</a></strong> and find what you are looking for in your region or in all India.</li></ul>











        </div>

<div id="regions">
























































































































        <div class="region_links_one">
            <ul class="regions_one">
                <li><a id="region_8" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4694186">Andhra Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_9" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4699188">Arunachal Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_10" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4692186">Assam</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_11" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4702186">Bihar</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_12" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4676188">Chhattisgarh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_13" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4702187">Goa</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4691189">Gujarat</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4700186">Haryana</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_16" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4703185">Himachal Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_17" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4694187">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_18" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4699189">Jharkhand</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_19" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4701185">Karnataka</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_20" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4695189">Kerala</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_21" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4697186">Madhya Pradesh</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="regions_two">
                <li><a id="region_22" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4694184">Maharashtra</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_23" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4700187">Manipur</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_24" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4703186">Meghalaya</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_25" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4698184">Mizoram</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_26" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4692187">Nagaland</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_27" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4696185">Orissa</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_28" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4693185">Punjab</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_29" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4701186">Rajasthan</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_30" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4701187">Sikkim</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_31" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4701188">Tamil Nadu</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_32" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4697187">Tripura</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_34" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4699190">Uttaranchal</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_33" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4692188">Uttar Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_35" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4700188">West Bengal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="region_links_two">
            <h2>Union territories</h2>


























            <ul class="regions_one">
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4699183">Delhi</a></li><li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4700189">Lakshadweep</a></li><li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4704183">Daman &amp; Diu</a></li><li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4691190">Dadra &amp; Nagar Haveli</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="regions_two">
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4704183">Chandigarh</a></li><li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4676189">Pondicherry</a></li><li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4703187">Andaman &amp; Nicobar Islands</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

</div>

    </div>

<div id="mapcontainer">
    <div id="map_map" class="sprite_index_in_in_map">
        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAOPr+AAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" id="area_highlight" alt="">
        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAOPr+AAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" id="area_map" usemap="#map_map_map" alt="">
    </div>
    <map name="map_map_map" id="map_map_map">



    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("#regions a").add("area").mouseover(function(){var id=this.id.substring(this.id.indexOf("_")+1);var regionmap=$("#hoverregion_"+id);if(regionmap&&regionmap.length>0){$("#area_highlight").removeClass().addClass("sprite_index_in_in_hover_region"+id);$("#region_"+id).css("text-decoration","underline");}});$("#regions a").add("area").mouseout(function(){var id=this.id.substring(this.id.indexOf("_")+1);var regionmap=$("#hoverregion_"+id);if(regionmap&&regionmap.length>0){$("#area_highlight").removeClass();$("#region_"+id).css("text-decoration","none");}});});</script>
</div>

<div class="fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" data-href="http://www.koolbusiness.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="30" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana" fb-xfbml-state="rendered">


</div>

<div class="google_plus">

</div>


</div><footer class="nohistory columns">

            <div class="widecolumn">
<p class="first">A good deal is just around the corner!</p>



    <p>KoolBusiness is the right choice for safe buying and selling in India: a free classifieds website where you can buy and sell almost everything.</p>



    <p><a href="/ai">Post an ad for free</a> or browse through our categories. You will find thousands of free classifieds for cars, houses, mobile phones and gadgets, computers, pets and dozens of items and services in your state or union territory.</p>



    <p class="last"><strong>KoolBusiness does not charge any fee and does not require registration.</strong> Every ad is checked so we can give you the highest quality possible for the ads on our site. That’s why KoolBusiness is the most convenient, easiest to use and most complete free ads site in India.</p>











</div>
<aside>


    <nav class="navbar ">
        <a class="first" href="/customer_service.htm">
            <i class="sprite_common_customer_service"></i>
            <span>Customer Service</span>
        </a><!--
        <a href="/security/index.htm">
            <i class="sprite_common_security"></i>
            <span>Shop safely</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/rules.htm">
            <i class="sprite_common_rules"></i>
            <span>Rules</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/about.htm">
            <i class="sprite_common_about_footer_in"></i>
            <span>About KoolBusiness.com</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/copyright.htm">
            <i>©</i>
            <span>Kool Ventures</span>
        </a>-->
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/koolbusiness" target="_blank">
                <i class="sprite_common_facebook"></i> 
                <span>Follow us on Facebook</span>
            </a>


    </nav>


</aside>
<div id="world_sites">
    <p>
        Travelling abroad? Visit our classifieds sites in other countries. See:<br> 








            ,  
            <a href="http://www.montao.com.br/" target="_blank">Montao.com.br</a>,  


    </p>
</div>


</footer>






</div><!-- / #wrapper  -->


    </body></html>
```

The entire HTML is [here](http://www.koolbusiness.com).

Comment: is it linux or because of resolution. can you reduce the lengths on left text or break it into mor lines?

Comment: It looks like your floated elements are one pixel away from breaking. If I make the `aside` width 202px instead of 201px, it breaks. Is it possible that your linux browser is zoomed out? Sometimes pixel rounding can cause tight pixel-perfect layouts to break.

Comment: @showdev It's working, you are correct.I accept you rcomment as an answer.

Comment: You have floated the div above it so you do not need to float the `aside` section. Remove the `float:left` atribute from it and see if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with pixel rounding.

Your floated elements are one pixel away from breaking.
If I make the aside width 202px instead of 201px, it breaks.

If your linux browser is zoomed out, it will round pixel values.
Upon rounding, the total width can exceed 100% causing tight pixel-perfect layouts to break.

Consider a more flexible layout, as suggested by JMurky.

Answer (score 2):

Since the left-side content is floated left and has a width defined, you don't really need to duplicate that in the right side content for what you're trying to accomplish. In the style rules defined in:

```
footer.columns aside
```

and

```
.columns aside
```

try removing the float:left; and width attributes from both of these selectors.